# Problem with Protext Setup

Tags: installing, protext

I downloaded `ProText.exe`, and was about to start Setup according to `protext-install-en.pdf`. But an error popped up. And in `Setup.exe`, it says this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "protext-setup.py", line 298, in <module>
  File "protext-setup.py", line 97, in __init__
  File "wx\_controls.pyc", line 494, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-5: illegal multibyte sequence
```

What does this mean? What should I do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a ProTeXt internal or Windows issue.